# Rolling count of unique values by unequal group using R

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, vertical-scrolling, rolling-computation

I am trying to create an indicator for number of changes in a character column in a rolling window (e.g. 12 obs.) but by group. Without grouping, this is possible with `rollapply` and data.table's `uniqueN` using **data.table**:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
df <- data.table(id = c(rep(1:5, each = 53), 5), 
             time = c(rep(1:53, times = 5), 54), 
             geo = c("E","E","E","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D","D","D","G","G","G","G","G","E","E","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","I","I","I","I","I","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","H","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","I","I","I","I","I","I","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","F","F","A","A","A","A","A"))

# works
df[, change := rollapply(geo, width = 12, FUN = uniqueN, na.pad = TRUE, align = "right")]
```

But when I group them by **id**, it does not work

```
# does not work
df[, change := rollapply(geo, width = 12, FUN = uniqueN, na.pad = TRUE, align = "right"), by = id]
```

Is there a way to do rolling unique count, preferably with **data.table**?

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work ? Works fine with me but with a warning message stating `1: In rollapply.zoo(zoo(data), ...) : na.pad argument is deprecated`.  I would use `df[, change := rollapplyr(geo, width = 12, FUN = uniqueN,fill = NA), by = id]`

Comment: length(unique(.)) might be faster if there are many groups

Comment: The issue was resolved by wrapping `rollapply` function in `as.numeric`, because variable change was being created as logical and could not handle any numbers than 0 and 1 (or NA)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by wrapping `rollapply` function in `as.numeric`, because variable **change** was being created as logical and could not handle numbers other than 0 and 1 (and NA).

This might be helpful for others to note if we leave this question open.

```
# works
df[, change := as.numeric(rollapplyr(geo, width = 12, FUN = uniqueN, fill = NA)), by = id]
```

Answer (score 1):

New fast version `rollapply` function is coming to `data.table`. It is called `frollapply`. It is not really that fast, but still should give some speed up.
It is not really that fast because it has to fallback to R's C `eval` function on each single iteration of rolling window.

It accept numeric or logical input, thus to address your data we need to make temporary `ngeo` column.

```r
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
df = data.table(
  id = c(rep(1:5, each = 53), 5), time = c(rep(1:53, times = 5), 54), 
  geo = c("E","E","E","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D","D","D","G","G","G","G","G","E","E","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","I","I","I","I","I","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","H","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","I","I","I","I","I","I","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","F","F","A","A","A","A","A")
)
dt = copy(df)

# zoo rollapply
df[, change := as.numeric(rollapplyr(geo, width=12, FUN=uniqueN, fill=NA)), by=id]

# data.table frollapply
dt[, ngeo := unclass(as.factor(geo))]
dt[, change := frollapply(ngeo, 12L, FUN=uniqueN), by=id]
dt[, ngeo := NULL]

all.equal(dt, df)
#[1] TRUE
```

It is not yet merged in the master branch of data.table, to try it out you have to

```r
devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table@frollapply")
```